# How to replace a pattern with newline (\n) with sed under UNIX / Linux operating systems?

Tags: unix, text, replace, sed, newline

I have a txt file which contains:

```
Some random
text here. This file
has multiple lines. Should be one line.
```

I use:

```
sed '{:q;N;s/\n/:sl:/g;t q}' file1.txt > singleline.txt
```

and get:

```
Some random:sl:text here. This file:sl:has multiple lines. Should be one line.
```

Now I want to replace the `:sl:` pattern with `newline (\n)` character. When I use:

```
sed 's/:sl:/&\n/g' singleline.txt
```

I get:

```
Some random:sl:
text here. This file:sl:
has multiple lines. Should be one line.
```

How to **replace** the pattern with newline character instead of **adding** newline character after the pattern?

Comment: `:sl:` pattern means?

Comment: `sed 's/:sl:/\n/g' singleline.txt`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `:sl:` means "single line". Can be anything else as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed uses `&` as a shortcut for the matched pattern. So you are replacing `:s1:` with `:s1:\n`.

Change your sed command like this:

```
sed 's/:sl:/\n/g' singleline.txt
```

Comment: Just FYI, this does not work with the macOS (and possibly BSD?) version of `sed`; from the man page: "You cannot, however, use a literal newline character in an address or in the substitute command." It may be necessary to install GNU sed with MacPorts or Homebrew (usually made available as `gsed`) if you expect this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more easily with tr : `tr '\n' ' ' < singleline.txt`