# Shell: How to append characters at the end of a string?

Tags: shell, unix, text, append

I need to write a shell script to append characters to each line in a text to make all lines be the same length. For example, if the input is:

```
Line 1 has 25 characters.
Line two has 27 characters.
Line 3: all lines must have the same number of characters.
```

Here "Line 3" has 58 characters (not including the `newline` character) so I have to append 33 characters to "Line 1" and 31 characters to "Line 2". The output should look like:

```
Line 1 has 25 characters.000000000000000000000000000000000
Line two has 27 characters.0000000000000000000000000000000
Line 3: all lines must have the same number of characters.
```

We can assume the max length (58 in the above example) is known.

Comment: Well, I'll give you starter... if you read the line into a variable called `line`, the length is `${#line}`

Comment: @grasGendarme No, that was not a homework exercise:) I discovered the `sed` (stream editor) utility this morning and started to play with it: replaced characters with patterns in a txt file, patterns with characters and so on. I even asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940591/how-to-replace-a-pattern-with-newline-n-with-sed-under-unix-linux-operating). Then I wanted to append characters to each line in a text using `sed` but could not. I was not sure if `sed` can do it so I asked this question without mentioning the `sed` utility.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you. This will help me now as I want my script to calculate the length of each line, take the maximum and append necessary characters to the shorter lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
while read -r; do                                 # Read from the file one line at a time
    printf "%s" "$REPLY"                          # Print the line without the newline
    for (( i=1; i<=((58 - ${#REPLY})); i++ )); do # Find the difference in length to iterate
        printf "%s" "0"                           # Pad 0s
    done
    printf "\n"                                   # Add the newline
done < file
```

#### Output:

```
Line 1 has 25 characters.000000000000000000000000000000000
Line two has 27 characters.0000000000000000000000000000000
Line 3: all lines must have the same number of characters.
```

Of course this is easy if you know the max length of the line. If you don't then you need to read the file in an array keep track of the length of each line and keeping the length of the line which is longest in a variable. Once you have completely read the file, you iterate your array and do the same `for loop` shown above.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print length($0)}' <file_name> | sort -nr | head -1
```

you would not need a loop to find the highest length

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cryptic one:

```
perl -lpe '$_.="0"x(58-length)' file
```